# Encountered a runtime exception when running code

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to interact my web app with azure api. I got this php exception error. Can anyone tell me what is it?

RuntimeException: The provided config value '[http | https]' does not belong to the valid values subset:

This is my code (account key has been deleted):

```
$conn_string="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=[http | https];AccountName=storage;AccountKey=..."; 

$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($conn_string);
```

Comment: have you tried if it works when specifying _1_ endpoint protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Storage Connection String` is indeed invalid.

The value `[http | https]` is just a placeholder you copied from somewhere, it denotes that you have to pick `http` or `https` to configure whether you want to connect to your storage data over regular or secure http.

Simply try:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountKey=... etc
```

And BTW, **you're exposing your account key to the public**!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either `http` or `https`, not both.